# Latex page number displays lower left, not lower right

Tags: latex

Hello I have this code, but the page numbers appear lower left, how do I tell it to be lower right?

```
%\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[text line]{\insertframenumber}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use:

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
```

the page numbers will appear bottom right